# Is there a psql command to show table definitions?

Tags: postgresql, psql

The [sqlite3](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) CLI has a command `.schema` that will display the columns of all tables in the database.

The [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-psql.html) CLI for PostgreSQL has a meta-commands `\d` that shows columns for all "relations" (table, view, index, sequence, or foreign table) and a meta-command `\dt` that lists the relations that are tables but does not show the columns of those tables.

Is there a way to get `psql` to show output like sqlite3's `.schema` - show the output of `\d` on just relations that are tables?  `\d *` shows columns for all relations, which in my database of 32 tables contains 63 tables and sequences.  The pattern (`*` in this example) seems able to match on relation name but not relation type.  Is there a pattern for "match all tables"?

Comment: `select * from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 'public';`

Comment: That command does indeed return something, but it's not very useful in its raw form.  Is there a way to trim the columns from something like 34 to the 4 I'm interested in: table_name, column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length?   I don't really care about the other 30 columns, e.g., collation_name, domain_catalog, domain_schema, udt_catalog, ... maximum_cardinaltiy, dtd_identifier, is_self_referencing, ...identity_start, identity_increment, identity_maximum, ...  you get the picture.

Comment: Obviously yes, like in any other SQL query: `select table_name, column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length from ...`.

Comment: sqlite provides [pragma](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) for obtaining various data about DB. Most of other DBMSes provides special tables/views for such purpose. Native clients wraps some of this to shortcuts like `.schema` in sqlite or `\d` in PostgreSQL but obviously that them can not provide the command for every usecase.

Answer (score 5):

If you want this like output:

```
sqlite> .schema t24
CREATE TABLE t24 (
    i integer,
    t text
);
```

You should use `pg_dump -s`, not `psql`:

```
bash>pg_dump -t t24 -s
CREATE TABLE t24 (
    i integer,
    t text
);
```

It created DDL just like `.schema`...

Now regarding the queries in comments, if you modify them a little:

```
t=# \d t24
      Table "public.t24"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers
--------+---------+-----------
 i      | integer |
 t      | text    |

t=# SELECT a.attname as "Column",pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) as "Type",
  (SELECT substring(pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) for 128)
   FROM pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d
   WHERE d.adrelid = a.attrelid AND d.adnum = a.attnum AND a.atthasdef) as "Modifiers"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
join pg_catalog.pg_class  c  on a.attrelid = c.oid
WHERE true
  AND relname like 't24'
  AND c.relkind = 'r'::"char"
  AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY relname, a.attnum;
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers
--------+---------+-----------
 i      | integer |
 t      | text    |
(2 rows)
```

This query will show only tables in same manner as `\d` meta-command.

BTW I took the query from this metacommand. If you launch `psql -E`, and run '\d table_name` you will see that all meta commands are just wraps for select queries...